# How to send in REST response excel file in go with swagger?

Tags: excel, go, swagger, xlsx, swagger-editor

I'm trying to send in response excel file, but in it I get binary data. If try use reponse data as xlsx file, Excel show that it is corrupted. However if save it locally, everything is fine. For create xlsx file I'm using tealeg/xlsx. What am I doing wrong?

Go:

```
file := xlsx.NewFile()
...
// filling file with data
...
// works fine
err = file.Save("asd.xlsx")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(err.Error())
}
// something went wrong
buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
if err := file.Write(buffer); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
r := bytes.NewReader(buffer.Bytes())
cr := ioutil.NopCloser(r)
```

Swagger:

```
get:
      tags:
        - "Report"
      summary: ""
      description: ""
      consumes:
        - "application/json"
      produces:
        - "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
      responses:
        200:
          description: ""
          schema:
            type: file
```

Comment: After days of trying, didn't solve. To make it work I encode file in base64 and send in response, then each client may easily decode it. Not best way, but with small size files(~1MB) it work nice

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Content-Type header before writing the xlsx payload over http.

```
    r.Header.Set("Content-Type","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

Comment: I thought about it, but do not understand where I shall use it, because I cannot see any possibility to set headers working with code generated by "go generate"

Comment: I assume you are writing this code in a http.Handler or http.HandlerFunc that means you should have access to http.ResponseWriter interface. Other wise i don't see how you can send the xls file output via http.